# Python form scrape and submit

Tags: python, forms

I am not having much success submitting this form (I'm only two days old in python coding)

What is the best/easiest way to parse it and submit? (parse not scrape - thanks Jason)

I cannot use mechanize browser for a few non-relevant reasons and would prefer to avoid Selenium unless it is necessary

```
<form id="theform" action="../login.asp?tx=" method="post">
   <input type=hidden name=E8IyqHS value='kgDcZHY+nV' >
   <input type=hidden name=DDSddfD value='KFSJXPH6De' >
   <input type=hidden name=AaaiJMK value='' >
   <input type=hidden name=pGmyGYt value='Ozz9WrvjYO' >
   <input type=hidden name=On3OTo9 value='wlAzaxtdwN' >      

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
      document.getElementById('theform').submit();
   </script>
</form>
```

Comment: So you want to parse the values from an HTML form and then POST them in python? Take a look at Requests and BeautifulSoup

Comment: Thanks you are right, parse not scrap. I'll explore this further. But in the meanwhile if anyone is feeling altruistic, I'd love an example :)